# Table definition issues in Apache HIVE

Tags: hadoop, hive, mapreduce, hiveql

Following is the data-set I pushed in a **Hive** table named **temp_stat** :

```
COUNTRY    CITY                 TEMP 
---------- -------------------- -----
US         Arizona              51.7 
US         California           56.7 
US         Bullhead City        51.1 
India      Jaisalmer            42.4 
Libya      Aziziya              57.8 
Iran       Lut Desert           70.7 
India      Banda                42.4
```

When I tried to view data though the **select** command, then I get the following data-set:

```
US,Arizona,51.7         NULL    NULL
US,California,56.7      NULL    NULL
US,Bullhead City,51.1   NULL    NULL
India,Jaisalmer,42.4    NULL    NULL
Libya,Aziziya,57.8      NULL    NULL
Iran,Lut Desert,70.7    NULL    NULL
India,Banda,42.4        NULL    NULL
```

Next I wanted to group these record abased on country and fetch maximum temperature for each country along with the city name, so I ran the following query:

```
select country,city,temp
from (
select country,city,temp, 
     row_number() over (partition by country order by temp desc) as part
from temp_stat
) a 
where part = 1
order by country, city;
```

Once I run the above query in **hive** shell, I get the following result :

```
US,Arizona,51.7         NULL    NULL
US,California,56.7      NULL    NULL
US,Bullhead City,51.1   NULL    NULL
India,Jaisalmer,42.4    NULL    NULL
Libya,Aziziya,57.8      NULL    NULL
Iran,Lut Desert,70.7    NULL    NULL
India,Banda,42.4        NULL    NULL
```

Even if I run the inner query to generate **row_number** then also I get similar ***row-numbers*** for all the records.
(Something like this :)

```
India,Banda,42.4        NULL    NULL    1
India,Jaisalmer,42.4    NULL    NULL    1
Iran,Lut Desert,70.7    NULL    NULL    1
Libya,Aziziya,57.8      NULL    NULL    1
US,Arizona,51.7         NULL    NULL    1
US,Bullhead City,51.1   NULL    NULL    1
US,California,56.7      NULL    NULL    1
enter code here
```

I also tried **dense_rank()** and **rank()**. No new results.Is there any issue with the table definition or what ?

All help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**fields terminated by ','**

---

Your table definition should be something like that:

```
create external table temp_stat
(
    country     string   
   ,city        string          
   ,temp        decimal(11,1)
)
    row format delimited
    fields terminated by ','
;
```

---

```
select * from temp_stat;
```

---

```
+---------+---------------+------+
| country |     city      | temp |
+---------+---------------+------+
| US      | Arizona       | 51.7 |
| US      | California    | 56.7 |
| US      | Bullhead City | 51.1 |
| India   | Jaisalmer     | 42.4 |
| Libya   | Aziziya       | 57.8 |
| Iran    | Lut Desert    | 70.7 |
| India   | Banda         | 42.4 |
+---------+---------------+------+
```

Comment: Is that reason my query was'nt giving me the correct output ?

Comment: Yes. Your table is not defined correctly. The whole row is mapped to the first column and all the other columns contain null values.

Comment: Thanks mate!
The table was really the problem. I followed you method and loaded the data likewise and my query ran just smooth.There is this one issue though. When I run the following query :

    select country,city,temp,rank() over (partition by country order by 
    temp desc)rank from temp_stat;

Comment: I get similar ranks for the rows which has similar temperatures even though they have different cities. Can you suggest why?

Comment: please edit the post, leaving only the table definition issue and open a new post for the query issue. It is important that you'll add the required results to your data sample

Comment: I am not creating a new question regarding the query issue since I got the required result through **_row_number()_**. I will do the same if I face any issues in future.

Comment: Great. Good luck!